# Two simple MySQL statements causing syntax error

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I'm confounded.  The following MySQL query:

```
SET @a := 0;   

SELECT * 
  FROM users;
```

Gives the error:

> Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT * FROM users' at line 2`

When I switch the order of the statements, I get the same error, again on line 2 (even though I switched them)

However, either line by themselves runs fine.  What could possibly cause this?

Comment: How do you try to perform this queries? From mysql console? Many of mysql clients does not accept multi-queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I bet you're trying to perform this query in the `mysql_query()` (or some similar function from any programming language), but it accepts only single query. So the solution is to split this queries into 2 calls.

Comment: I was trying to use a variable in a future statement but kept getting syntax errors so I kept stripping out parts until I was left with that and still getting errors, at which point I signed up here to ask you guys :P

Comment: @maackle: well, how do you perform these queries?

Comment: With separate calls to mysql_query() for each query.

Comment: @Dan Grossman: if it is **separated** queries - how is it possible that "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT * FROM users' at line **2** "? Please give in the question post actual code you're trying to run.

Comment: I answered your question "how do you perform these queries?" with "with separate calls to mysql_query()".

The reason you got that error was because you did NOT use separate calls to mysql_query(). Your SINGLE query was wrong as soon as you put something after the semicolon.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it in one query as follows:

**The trick**

```
select @a:=@a+1, u.* 
from 
 users u 
join (select @a:=0) a
```

or be adventerous and use a stored procedure so it's always a single call :P

**Stored procedure**

```
drop procedure if exists list_users;
delimiter #

create procedure list_users()
begin
 set @a = 0;
 select @a:=@a+1, u.* from users u;
end #

delimiter ;

call list_users();
```

**PHP script**

```
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "foo_dbo", "pass", "foo_db", 3306);

$result = $conn->query("call list_users()");

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
 ...
}

$result->close();
$conn->close();
```